# Reformatting MySQL table from Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, view, triggers

I am pretty new to the MySQL world and I have been placed into a position where I use it frequently. The current issue I am having is that we are receiving data from multiple different sites that contain many columns such as Table1 below:

```
DateTime | Temperature1 | Temperature2 | Temperature3 | Ect.
```

A lot of our engineers like to pull this data into excel sheets and more specifically pivot tables for easy manipulation. We also have a few programs that use this data to produce graphs, ect. These programs in particular require the data to be in a format as follows:

DateTime |  pValue | pName

With pValue being the values of the temperature columns and pName being the column name from which that value came. I have tried with not much success to create a simple view to reformat the data in the format above. Instead I have resorted to an extremely long View written as follows;

```
SELECT `DateTime` AS `DateTime`,
       `Temperature1` AS `pValue`,
       'Temperature1' AS `pName` 
FROM `table1` 
UNION
SELECT `DateTime` AS `DateTime`,
       `Temperature2` AS `pValue`,
       'Temperature2' AS `pName` 
FROM `table1`
```

The code then repeats itself for every individual temperature column. It worked when we only had a small amount of data, but as the data coming in increases, the duration of our queries decrease and it is becoming quite an issue. From what I have read online, using a view may not be the way to go for a large data set such as this especially considering I cannot index any of it. I have thought about creating a trigger to write the data as it is being inserted into a new reformatted table, but I have no idea how to begin.

All in all, I am just looking for some guidance on what might be the most efficient way to reformat this data. Would a trigger serve this purpose better or do I just need a better optimized view. Or is there a third option that I have not even thought of yet?

Comment: Don't store your temperature readings as multiple columns. This is called "repeating groups" and it's not a recommended database design, because of the difficulties you are having now. Instead, store temperatures one per row.

Comment: The issue is that the programs used to collect and send data to our database can only send the data in "repeating groups". It has to do with timestamp syncing as the system will collect the data at one specific timestamp and then write all of the collected data into one specific row. Unless we offset each piece of recorded data by a second or two we could not achieve one temperature reading per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store your temperature readings as multiple columns. This is called "repeating groups" and it's not a recommended database design, because of the difficulties you are having now. Instead, store temperatures one per row.

You can create a trigger on the table that receives your instrument data, so that it *also* inserts multiple rows in to to a properly organized table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER FixDataInputs AFTER INSERT ON MyRepeatingGroupsTable
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO MyNormalizedTable (DateTime, Temperature, Instrument) 
  VALUES (NEW.DateTime, NEW.Temperature1, 1),
         (NEW.DateTime, NEW.Temperature2, 2),
         (NEW.DateTime, NEW.Temperature3, 3),
         (NEW.DateTime, NEW.Temperature4, 4);
```

Now you can query the new table more easily.

Comment: Thanks Bill this looks like a great starting point. The only issue is that I will not have any idea which temperature is which. I may have posed the question in a confusing manner. Temperature1, Temperature2 ect. are all different temperature sensors. So I would need an indicator to tell me which temperature is from which sensor.

Comment: See edit above. That's just an example. You can indicate the sensor with some other value, whatever makes sense to you.